# apache - Treat '?' character as part of filename

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have directory with a lot of files containing the question mark character. How can I disable query string support in Apache (possibly using mod_rewrite) so it treats `?` as an ordinary character? I do NOT want to change filenames with `?`.

Current behavior:

```
Request URI: /dir/subdir/file?abcdef.txt
Served file: /dir/subdir/file
```

Requested behavior:

```
Request URI: /dir/subdir/file?abcdef.txt
Served file: /dir/subdir/file?abcdef.txt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apache, allow filenames with '?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033546/apache-allow-filenames-with)

Comment: @MostafaHussein, No, I want to do it on the server without changing links.

Comment: What is the exact Apache version?

Comment: @DusanBajic, `apache-2.4.34-r2::gentoo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) $1\%3f%{QUERY_STRING} [QSD]
```